# What are the tax implications on selling the Share ISA portfolio?

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I am new to Stock and Share ISA investing. I am planning to make use of the New ISA limit of £15000 from this year. I am aware that the profit or loss made out of Share ISA is tax free.

Does this mean that even as a higher rate tax payer, if I make a profit out of share ISA of around 30K in any year on selling my ISA portfolio, would it be completely tax free of Capital Gains Tax or would I need to pay the CGT limit (£11000) minus the profit obtained on selling my portfolio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets held within an ISA or New ISA [are completely free of CGT](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax/what-you-pay-it-on), so you won't have to pay either income tax or capital gains tax.

Comment: Isa investors can not claim back the 10pc tax credit on dividends so you do pay a small amount of tax